# Stack multiple mask on a one image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I am trying to stack multiple masks(6) on a reference image.

1. I have 6 images on which I performed edge detection followed by dilation.
2. Gaussian Blur on dilated images to remove noise.
3. Binary masking using threshold as shown [Binary Mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQmkc.jpg)
4. Retrieved region from original image only for masked area[Bitwise_and result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xo3lR.jpg)
5. Found a reference image(most blurred) on which each individual extracted regions will be super imposed.
6. Put the extracted regions on the reference image as shown [Combined Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1hAr.jpg)
   Thanks in advance!

```
def masking(file_list):
#read images
    for file in glob.glob(path):
        img = cv2.imread(file)        

        #edge detection
        canny = auto_canny(img)

        #Dilation(Morphological function to increase edge width)
        img_dilate = cv2.dilate(canny, (3,3), iterations = 1)

        #Gaussian Blur to blur the edges to remove noise
        very_blurred = ndimage.gaussian_filter(img_dilate, sigma=5)

        #Apply Threshold to generate mask
        ret, thresh1 = cv2.threshold(very_blurred, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY) #cv2.THRESH_TOZERO

        #Retrieve regions from original images
        res = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask = thresh1)
        return res
```

This performs the masking and returns the original regions from the images.

```
def variance_of_laplacian(file_list):
    blurriest = 0 
    blurr = 0
    # compute the Laplacian of the image and then return the focus
    # measure, which is simply the variance of the Laplacian
    for file in file_list:
        image = cv2.imread(file)
#         gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        canny = auto_canny(image)
        blur_extent = cv2.Laplacian(canny, cv2.CV_64F).var()

        if blurr == 0:
            blurr = blur_extent
        if blur_extent < blurr:
            blurr = blur_extent
            blurriest = image

#         print(bb, blur_extent)
    return blurriest
```

This returns the reference image to be used for stacking all the masks with original regions cut from images.

Now I tried adding the masks to the base image but it didn't work out. Can anyone suggest how to proceed.

```
added_image = cv2.addWeighted(b,1.0,res,0.7,0)

cv2.imshow('combined', added_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

**EDIT:**

```
for i in range(len(image_1)):
    b = cv2.addWeighted(b,0.5,image_1[i],0.5,0)


# # new = cv2.add(blurring,b)
added_image = cv2.addWeighted(blurring,0.5,b,0.5,0)
cv2.imshow("final",added_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Here image1 is a list with all the extracted regions. Blurring is a copy of the reference image onto which all extracted regions are added.

This is final result after adding all the mask and putting together the extracted regions on the reference image. [Final Image after adding masks and putting on the reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFaUM.jpg)

Comment: I am not sure I understand. But if your masks are binary, then you can just add them together and clip before applying them to  the image. Or you can apply them to the image one at a time for each mask. If I misunderstand, please clarify further and show the masks.

Comment: @fmw42 Well what I am trying to do is using the masks I am trying to get only those regions from the original pictures in which we have the white region in the mask. Then super imposing that region on the reference blurred image as shown in Bitwise_and Result image provided above. Now I want to do this for all the images. You have suggested that we can binary masks and then apply it to the photos but how to get the bitwise results from them then. I hope it clears some doubts.

Comment: @fmw42 I'll edit the question for a much better understanding.

Comment: I think perhaps all you want to do is add all the masked results together and clip to the 0 to 1 range or the 0 to 255 range depending upon the dtype.

Comment: @fmw42 I have edited the question with sample results. I hope it clears what I am trying to do.

Comment: @fmw42 yes I want to add all the binary masks together in such a way that they have got extracted regions from original images. Having done that I want to paste them onto a base image. Sample images attached in the edited question.

Comment: Do the individual regions overlap? If not, then just do all your steps for each image -- extract mask, apply mask to the image, put the result onto the reference image. If they do overlap, does it matter and if so why, if you put one region on top of the other onto the reference?

Comment: @fmw42 Well they do overlap. And to avoid the overlapping one approach I thought was to take regions from the mask with most edge points in it. For example, if mask 1 and mask 2 overlap and mask 1 has 50 points in the overlapped region while mask 2 has 30 edge points it should take the mask with max edges(mask 1 in this case). I have added the result of the approach you mentioned but the result is not as desired. Any pointers on how to improve it. And using this approach the extracted regions are not even same as the mask

Comment: @fmw42 If I put one region on top of other onto the reference image there is misalignment of the regions as shown in the sample output. Can they be an image registration problem or due to the overlapping regions?

Comment: `@Happy` If all the input images are not the same size and alignment, then you will need to align them first before any other processing. You can use ORB or SIFT feature detection and then affine or perspective warping to register them. Once you have them all aligned, you can do your loop processing to get the mask, extract the regions and then overlay them onto the reference image. If they are registered already, then please clarify further as I then do not understand the issue.

Comment: @fmw42 they are already aligned and the issue right now is how to add the multiple masks onto the reference image because the result I have provided is not what I expected. Instead the regions should be sharper where the mask is applied in the reference image.

Comment: `@Happy`. I think they might not be sharp because you create the mask from a laplacian operation. That means the mask is not binary and blends the extracted regions with the reference. So try thresholding your masks after blurring to create them.

Comment: @fmw42 sorry I didn't understand that. I am thresholding the blurred dilated images to create the masks from them. Am I not doing what you mentioned?

Comment: `@Happy`. Yes, sorry I was looking in the wrong place. But you seem to be using addWeight to insert. I would think that would blend the extracted with the reference. You should be replacing the reference by the extracted where the mask is white. Perhaps I misunderstand, since I am not  following your code very well. Best I can suggest is to view each step of your process to see what is happening.

Comment: @fmw42 how do you suggest doing that? Replacing the reference by the extracted where the mask is white?

Comment: result = combined * mask + reference * (1-mask), where mask is in the range 0 to 1. And you may have convert back and forth between float and int.

Comment: This was a command I used in another answer that needed similar replacing. `result = (mask * blurred_image + (1.0 - mask) * image).clip(0, 255).astype(np.uint8)`

Comment: @fmw42 I'll give it a try and I really appreciate you spending time on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to cut a part of an image and paste it on top of another? if so, `addWeighted` is not the right function, because it blends the entire image, not just the area you want.

Repeat this process for each of the 6 images.

Get the part you want to copy (you already have this):

```
bitwise_and_result = cv2.bitwise_and(img, img, mask = thresh1)
```

[image]

Invert the mask and apply it to the main image:

```
thresh1_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(thresh1)
main_altered = cv2.bitwise_and(main_img, main_img, mask = thresh1_inv)
```

[image]

Combine the images:

```
result = cv2.add(main_altered , bitwise_and_result )
```

[image]

Write your code so that for the next image the altered main_image is used. For instance:
`main_img = result`

You can find an example [here](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_core/py_image_arithmetics/py_image_arithmetics.html#bitwise-operations)

If you want to paste multiple section, you can repeat the process. Take the output as the new main image:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll  clear up what I am trying to do. I have 6 images on which I have done edge detection followed by dilation. Then I applied the gaussian blur to remove the noise(on edge detected dilated images). Then I used thresholding to generate binary masks for all images. Now, I have 6 masks for 6 images. For the white regions of the masks, I got actual image regions using bitwise_and as shown in the sample result above(Bitwise_and Result). Now I have 6 images with actual regions from original images only for the masked part.

Comment: Reading the comments I still think this is want, but you don't fully understand what I mean. I updated the answer with some images that can help you understand my meaning.

Comment: what would be the main_img parameter in my code. I got confused at this step ```main_altered = cv2.bitwise_and(main_img, main_img, mask = thresh1_inv)```. Will that be the blurred image I am using as reference?

Comment: Correct, it's the image you paste on to. The 'lowest layer' so to speak.

Comment: first of all thank you for this. I just have one more question. This way I will get a copy of mask on a reference image(in this case 6 copies of different masks on one reference image). How to add all these masks on one picture. I mean all masks on one reference image.

Comment: create a empty image `new_img = np.zeros((main_img.shape[:2]))` . Next you can add in the regions of interest using above technique. If you just want to combine the (black and white) masks use `combined_masks = cv2.bitwise_or(mask1, mask2)`

Comment: thanks for your time on this. It worked on the reference image but I am still getting 6 instances. When I tried using ```new_img``` it gave an error ```error: (-5) When the input arrays in add/subtract/multiply/divide functions have different types, the output array type must be explicitly specified in function cv::arithm_op```

Comment: how to add multiple images on the green background. Like I mentioned I have 6 copies of extracted regions which I want to put on the reference image. And currently I am using a loop so I have 6 different instances of Reference image+Extracted image but I want all those extracted regions on one reference image and only 1 final output. Is there a way to achieve it.

Comment: Simply repeat  the process using the output image. I've added an example.